# Как сделать проверку на недопустимые символы при вводе пароля?

Tags: c#

```
string Spl_Chars = "$%^&*";
if (pas.IndexOf(Spl_Chars) > 0)
{
    ErrorFlag_5 = true;
    MessageBox.Show("Вы ввели недопустимые символы.", "Ошибка");
}
else
    MessageBox.Show("Вы ввели непопустимые символы.", "Ошибка");
```

pas - то `TextBox`, куда пользователь вбивает пароль.

У меня должен стоять запрет на ввод символов, указанных в `Spl_Chars`, но ничего не работает. Если ставить проблем между символами - это помогает, но в таком случае он считает пробел, как недопустимый символ, а этого быть не должно

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите код текстом, а не картинкой

Comment: @АндрейNOP правил)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш код работает не так как вы ожидаете, потому что метод `string.IndexOf` возвращает индекс вхождения подстроки в строку, т. е. он вернет не -1 только в том случае, если в проверяемой строке есть целиком подстрока `$%^&*`, а не какой-то символ из нее.

Исправить можно, например, так:

```
if (pas.Intersect(Spl_Char).Any())
```

Linq-операция Intersect возвращает пересечение множеств. В данном случае строки считаем множествами из символов. Если пересечение не пустое — значит введены какие-то запретные символы.

Если это место когда-то станет узким (в чем я сомневаюсь), можно будет сохранить набор запрещенных символов в HashSet (один раз) и переписать проверку как-то так:

```
var splCharSet = new HashSet<char>(Spl_Char);
...
if (pas.Any(c => splCharSet.Contains(c)))
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Если не использовать Linq, то ваш пример можно модифицировать, например, так:

```
ErrorFlag_5 = false;
string Spl_Chars = "$%^&*";

foreach (var c in Spl_Chars)
{
    if (pas.IndexOf(c) > 0)
    {
        ErrorFlag_5 = true;
        MessageBox.Show("Вы ввели недопустимые символы.", "Ошибка");
        break;
    }
}

if (!ErrorFlag_5)
    MessageBox.Show("В пароле нет недопустимых символов", "ОК");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static bool ValidPass(string password, string notAllowedChar)
{
   return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(password) && !Regex.IsMatch(password, notAllowedChar);
}
```

Я использовал это.